# Python list | How to remove parenthesis,quotes and commas in my list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

From my database, I'm returning a list to be displayed into my HTML page but my list has this unwanted symbols. I tried using `split()` function but it wont work. How can I remove those parenthesis,commas and quotes. Thanks for you help

**The output is :**

```
[('cenomar',), ('cedula',), ('Birth Certificate',), ('Clearance',)]
```

**I want:**

```
 [cenomar, cedula, Birth Certificate, Clearance]
```

**Here is my python function:**

```
 @app.route('/')
    def search():
        conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='forms' user='postgres' password='everboy' 
       host='localhost' port='5432'")
       cur=conn.cursor()
       cur.execute("SELECT name from form")
       rows=cur.fetchall()
       print(rows)
       return render_template("form.html",rows=rows)
```

Comment: It seems that each element in you list is a tuple. You want to get the data inside the tuple right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After This line: `rows=cur.fetchall()`
add this line

```
rows=[i[0] for i in rows]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be:

> **Input**: ["('cenomar',)", "('cedula',)", "('Birth Certificate',)", "('Clearance',)"]

```
rows = ["('cenomar',)", "('cedula',)", "('Birth Certificate',)", "('Clearance',)"]
res = []
for r in rows:
    res.append(r[2:-3]) # this line ignores the beginning bracket and open quote and the closing bracket, comma, and close quote
print res
```

> **Output**: ["cenomar", "cedula", "Birth Certificate", "Clearance"]

What happens is, you iterate over your list, and for each item you just cut off the things you don't need with the use of string manipulation (`[n:m]`, where `n` is the starting character and `m` is the end character, in your case `2` indicates to start the string from the 3 character (ignoring the `(` and `'`) and `-3` indicates cut the string to 3 characters before the end of it (ignoring the `)`, `'`, and `,`)).

**EDIT 1**

I noticed that your input may not be a string as my above answer suggests, if you have a tuple `("smth",)` you can just simply get the 1st element. So the answer would change to:

> **Input**: [('cenomar',), ('cedula',), ('Birth Certificate',), ('Clearance',)]

```
rows = [('cenomar',), ('cedula',), ('Birth Certificate',), ('Clearance',)]
res = []
for r in rows:
    res.append(r[0])
print res
```

> **Output**: ["cenomar", "cedula", "Birth Certificate", "Clearance"]

The above implementation is written in long for ease of understanding, but as well can be translated into a shorter one liner like so:

```
rows = [i[0] for i in rows]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the same input than the question had

Comment: @ingofreyer I just noticed that and have updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this looks way better :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
l = [('cenomar',), ('cedula',), ('Birth Certificate',), ('Clearance',)]
b = []
for i in l:
    b.append(i[0])
print(b)
```